# Qt Code editor display the line number in an area to the RIGHT

Tags: c++, qt, numbers, line

I am just learning Qt. I want to show line number of QPlainTextEdit. I found [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html)
and it worked. But now I want the editor displays the line numbers in an area to the RIGHTof the area for editing. I have been searching google very much, but I can't solve. How to solve?

Comment: I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your link it shows you how it draws the line number area on the left:

> ```
> void CodeEditor::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
> {
>     QPlainTextEdit::resizeEvent(e);
>
>     QRect cr = contentsRect();
>     lineNumberArea->setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(), lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()));
> }
> ```

In order to draw the line numbers from the right you will (this is untested) do something like this:

```
void CodeEditor::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
    QPlainTextEdit::resizeEvent(e);

    QRect cr = contentsRect();
    lineNumberArea->setGeometry(QRect(cr.right() - lineNumberArea->width() , cr.top(), lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to GPPK's answer, you also need to change the viewport margins:

```
void CodeEditor::updateLineNumberAreaWidth(int /* newBlockCount */)
{
   setViewportMargins(0, 0, lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0);
}
```

GPPK's code assigns the correct drawing rectangle to the sub-widget, my code makes sure, that the scrollview does not paint into that area.